# Styling for Mobile; "Choose File" Button Too Small in iOS 6

Tags: asp.net, html, css, ios6, safari

I'm currently working on styling a couple of simple form pages originally written in ASP.NET for mobile. I'm using media detection in CSS3 to determine if the device is mobile, and if it is, I basically make everything look bigger. This has worked so far in most of the phones I've tested, but in iOS6, the "choose file" button stubbornly refuses to get bigger like every other element. I've tried styling it by its ID or just through all inputs, and while I can change the color or the font, the size never changes. How can I make the choose file button look bigger?

My CSS page:

```
@import url(master.css);

/* --- page wrapper --- */
#wrapper { width:80%; margin:auto; max-width:1200px; position:relative; border:1px solid #000; background-color:#000; }
#main { width:100%; height:100%; border-bottom:1px solid #000; }
#content { height:100%; background-color:#CDCCCC; padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px; }
#login { text-align:center; }
#upload { padding:10px; }
#list {  display: inline; width: auto; height: auto; }
#logoutButton { display: inline; float: right; }
#guidelines {
    text-align:justify;
}
#flash { 
    padding: 20px; 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px), only screen and (max-device-width: 720px) {
     #logoutButton {
        display: inline;
        float: right;
    }
    #guidelines {
        background-image:url(http://cite.nwmissouri.edu/PhotoContest_MobileApp/transparentbg4androidwidthbug.png);
        background-repeat:repeat;
        text-align:inherit;
        height:100%; 
        background-color:#CDCCCC; 
    }
    #hwrapper {
        width:initial;
    }

    #contentum { 
        height: 100%; 
        width:inherit;
        background-color:#CDCCCC; 
        text-align:inherit; 
        font-size:40px; 
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    input {
        font-size:40px;
        height:inherit;
        width:inherit;
    }

    select {
        font-size:40px;
        height:auto;
        width:inherit;
    }

    #upload {
        font-size: 40px;
        text-align: start;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 12px;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width:inherit; 
        height:inherit; 
        margin:auto; 
        position:inherit; 
        border:1px solid #000; 
        background-color:#000; 
        overflow:scroll;
    }
    li {
        font-size: 40px;
        text-align: start;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's hard to tell what you've done to attempt to increase the size, and also which CSS you've pasted above isn't actually working. Try be a bit clearer with your question.

Comment: Hello! What I've pasted above is working for everything but the "choose file" button. The code I've used to attempt to style that uses its ID, "Content_fileUpload," and while I can change, say, the background color of the section where the button is, and even enlarge the section by changing the width and height, the button itself still won't change. Does that help make my question clearer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want the file upload (`<input type="file"/>`) button to display larger?

You should be able to use the following (non-standard) psuedo-element selector for WebKit:

```
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    /* add styles here, such as width, height etc. */
}
```

You can do the same in IE10 using (a similarly non-standard):

```
input[type="file"]::-ms-browse {
    /* add styles here, such as width, height etc. */
}
```